# Selenium + Java : Parallel execution for test cases having login functionality

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, parallel-execution

I have an application which requires a login and does not allow multiple logins of same account at a given time. So i have upto 60 such testcases. Currently i am handling their parallel execution as follows:

- Login in the @BeforeSuite with CredzSet1 by initializing a driver object. Save the cookies.
- In the @BeforeMethod set the cookies to the new driver object created and refresh. this displays the homepage of the application ie successfull login

I have come up with this method to avoid login/logout step for each testcase and to make parallel execution possible with a single credential set.

Now this method works just fine but i was thinking if there is any other alternate way as one thread gets occupied by the @BeforeSuite driver object for the entire execution time as i close that object only at the end of execution.?? want to utilize all the threads for parallel execution.

Here is the code:

public class TestConfigs {

```
protected static SelectEnv loadedEnv;
protected static BrowserManager factory;
protected static String url = null;
private static Set<Cookie> cookies;

@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)    
public void startSuite() {      
    try{            
        loadedEnv = ConfigFactory.create(SelectEnv.class);

        //Initiate browser
        factory = BrowserManager.getInstance();         
        factory.setAnyDriver("chrome"); 
        factory.getDriver().get(ConfigFactory.getProperty("url"));

        Login login = new Login(factory.getDriver(), db);
        //Logging in 
        login.verifyLogin(loadedEnv.usernameAU(), loadedEnv.password(), 
                  loadedEnv.accesscode()); 
         Thread.sleep(5000);

        //Saving cookies                
        cookies = factory.getDriver().manage().getCookies();


    }catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Exception in @BeforeSuite method");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }



@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public synchronized void testSetup(Method method, Object[] obj) {
    try {   
        System.out.println("********* In Before Method***************");

        //Initiate browser
        factory = BrowserManager.getInstance();
        // Initiate browser
        factory.setAnyDriver("chrome");
        factory.getDriver().get(url);

        if(cookies!=null) {
            cookies.forEach( cookie -> factory.getDriver().manage().addCookie( cookie ));
            factory.getDriver().get(url);               
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void cleanUp() {

    factory.getDriver().close();
    factory.getDriver().quit();


}


@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterSuiteCleanup() {       
    if(factory!=null && factory.getDriver() !=null) {
        factory.getDriver().close();
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can create a synchronized method as explained in https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized.

With a synchronized method only one thread can use the method at a time. Thus ensuring that only one logon occurs at a time.

So if you convert `login.verifyLogin()` to a synchronized method this should work.

Comment: I do not have an issue of synchronization. My question was regarding parallel execution with logging in functionality. what could be the approaches for running parallel testcases with same credentials.